# Redirect to mobile site (Pure HTML)

Tags: html, redirect

Does anybody know of a method for redirecting mobile users to a mobile site using pure HTML.

My clients website is located on a external multi-site system. We can only access the CMS and no scripts are allowed.

Hope someone can help, or at least give me some hints on what to do.

Cheers!

Comment: if javascript is allowed it is possible else it is impossible as far as i know, becouse html it not made to check things or redirect

Comment: Scripts arrent allowed :-(

Comment: Why aren't scripts allowed?

Comment: Can i use DNS in some way?

Comment: than it is impossbile

Comment: I asked the webmaster to add some javascript code but he replied that scripts aren't allowed

Comment: Allowed? Who is asking for the detection? the owner of the site?

Comment: I created a mobile-website for a client and i want to redirect mobile-users from ex: johndoe.com to johndoe.mobile.com.
There is an external host for johndoe.com. It is under a mulit-site system and therefore we can only access the CMS. They wont allow FTP access because other sites in their multi-site system might be affected to any changes (understandable). Sadly the editor in the CMS does not accept scripts only HTML and CSS.

Comment: So do the redirect the other way around. Send everyone to the mobile site and redirect desktop users to the old site.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible to redirect mobile user, becouse you cant check if a user is mobile with html. You can make with CSS your layout responsive you make css

here an example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
   #website{
     display:none;
    }
   #mobile{
     display:block;
   }
}
```